# How to enable AMD graphics card

Tags: command-line, additional-drivers

I have a laptop.
It has Intel HD and AMD card 
How to enable AMD card on linux (Kubuntu)
So that I can game on it

Answer (score -1):

I think `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` is enough for installing AMD drivers as well as updating AMD graphics drivers.

If that is not sufficient to fixed it, then search in the Additional Drivers section, accessible from the Unity dash or from Settings.